# xaml maui - how to change the color of the tab selector of a flyout menu?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, flyout

not sure what the element is actually called so open to changes to the question.

I want to change the color of whatever this is called. I've included the code for my DataTemplate as well as my styles for the menu as I assume its something to do with those.

[image]

**DATA TEMPLATE**

```
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Style="{StaticResource FlyoutItemStyle}" WidthRequest="280" ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *" Padding="0, 10, 0, 10">
                        <Image Source="{Binding FlyoutIcon}"
                         Margin="10"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         HorizontalOptions="Center"
                         HeightRequest="38"
                         WidthRequest="38" />

                        <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                         Text="{Binding Title}" 
                         FontSize="12"
                         HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                         x:Name="_label">
                            <Label.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Label">
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource AusDx_Gold}" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="TextColor"  Value="{StaticResource AusDx_Blue}" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Label.Style>
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
```

**STYLES**

```
<Style x:Key="FlyoutItemStyle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="_label" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Black" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

This select tab can be changed in the maui in windows/App.xaml.
You can add this code to Platforms->Windows-> App.xaml file.

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <StaticResource x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"  Color="Red" />
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

For more styles, you can see the WinUI source code [CommonStyles](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/tree/cb181acede22577c59c5dc250361d3340252f4e9/dev/CommonStyles).

Comment: Are there any other ways to do so ?

Comment: This belongs to the Winui format and this is the only way to change this color.

Comment: How do I Implement into my current code ? I add it and it tells me it is not recognized

Comment: You can put the code in the Platforms->Windows-> App.xaml file

Comment: Very good and interesting. The way you change specific WInUI details. In few months this will be quite useful to me.